# Проверка данных в структуре(struct) в windows forms приложении

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli

В моём приложении нужно создать проверку условия в зависимости от того что находиться в comboBox в свойстве Text если значение удовлетворяет условию оно должно добавляться в listbox2,но в моём случае это не происходит почему?Фрагмент кода:

```
    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        array <name^>^d;
        d = gcnew array<name^>(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            d[i] = gcnew name;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                d[i]->g = textBox1->Text;
                d[i]->instr = comboBox1->Text;
                listView1->Items->Add(d[i]->g);
                textBox1->Text = "";
                listView2->Items->Add(d[i]->instr);
                comboBox1->Text = "";
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                if (d[i]->instr == "Гитара") {
                    listBox2->Items->Add(d[i]->instr);
                    listBox2->Items->Add(d[i]->g);
                }
            }

        };
        ;
    };
    };
}
```

Comment: В чём смысл таких циклов: `for (int i = 0; i < 1;`?

Comment: И во внешнем, и во внутренних циклах используется переменная `i`.

Comment: Исправил проблему

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 1); используется у меня для добавления значений в listbox

Comment: Этот цикл выполняется **один** раз. Таким образом, в нем нет смысла. Можно его смело убрать. Или там все же должно быть другое ограничение вместо `i < 1` ?

Comment: мне нужно было проверять значение не combobox-а,а из textbox-а  то есть я убрал combobox и поставил textbox если допустим название муз.инструмента гитара,то добавляем из текстбокса фамилию в отдельный список

Comment: цикл я отставил из-за того,что мне нужно было добавить 1 раз фамилию в отдельный список,а не пять

Comment: Чтобы добавить **один** раз, цикл **не** нужен.

Comment: Спасибо,я в этом сейчас убедился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поменял элемент управления comboBox на элемент управления textBox и это решило мою проблему теперь при проверке значения в свойстве Text я могу рассортировать фамилии абитуриентов по спискам в зависимости от выбранного музыкального инструмента